# JavaFx display image instantly

Tags: java, javafx

Im making a Memory card game.

I want to be able to catch 2 clicks, display them and then compare them.

I tried to achieve this but it doesn't work the way i want it. The code ive written waits for two clicks, displays the first card and the secound card never displays because it will right away when it got 2 cards compare them, and if they aren't the same it will remove both cards.

```
  EventHandler<MouseEvent> keyEventHandler =
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    clickedCards(event);
                    if (klickade.size() == 2) {
                        boolean isSame = CardsAreSame();
                        if (isSame) {
                            firstMemoryCard.setPair(Boolean.TRUE);
                            secoundMemoryCard.setPair(Boolean.TRUE);
                            klickade.clear();
                        } else {
                            firstMemoryCard.setGraphic(firstMemoryCard.getImagEFaceDown());
                            secoundMemoryCard.setGraphic(secoundMemoryCard.getImagEFaceDown());
                            klickade.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

public void clickedCards(MouseEvent event) {
    MemoryCard memoryCard = (MemoryCard) event.getSource();
    klickade.add(memoryCard);
    memoryCard.setGraphic(memoryCard.getImageFaceUp());

    System.out.println(klickade.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just asking how you can put a delay in the code before you show the result of the user's guess.

The easiest way is to use a [`PauseTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html):

```
if (klickade.size() == 2) {
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
    pause.setOnFinished(event -> {
        boolean isSame = CardsAreSame();
        if (isSame) {
            firstMemoryCard.setPair(Boolean.TRUE);
            secoundMemoryCard.setPair(Boolean.TRUE);
            klickade.clear();
        } else {
            firstMemoryCard.setGraphic(firstMemoryCard.getImagEFaceDown());
            secoundMemoryCard.setGraphic(secoundMemoryCard.getImagEFaceDown());
            klickade.clear();
        }
    });
    pause.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for clicks counts you can use MouseEvent [mouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount()) and add your Logic

**mouseEvent.getClickCount()**

Comment: This isn't the problem. I can count the clicks. The problem is that when i get two clicks the program will not display the cards because it will right away compare them and close them if they aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the click counts on a MouseEvent by using [`getClickCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount--)

```
if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
    // your code
}
```

If you are only looking for the `Primary Button` clicks,

```
if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
     if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
         // your code
     }
}
```